# display only sql fields having values in asp

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp-classic

i am having a asp web page that retrieves value from sql...it shows the fields without having values..is there anyway to display only the fields having values..this is my table

[] [][] "Mfg Dt and Exp Dt as per Annexure enclosed"

this square brackets contain null values..if the field is empty then this square bracket will not come

[image: have to correct]

in first row i am having 2 sets of square brackets and in second row i am having the values in 2 sets..i need to show only the square bracket having values like in the second row..if the value is empty then dont want to show that empty brackets.

sql query

```
select I.[Old Product Code], I.[Trade Name], I.[Short Name], SUM(Quantity) as Qty,I.[Base Box UOM], SIH.[Customer Marks - 1] ,SIH.[Bill-to Name],SIH.[Bill-to Address], SIH.[Ship-to Name], SIH.[Ship-to Address], SIH.[Ship-to Address 2] ,SIH.[Ship-to City], SIH.[Ship-to Post Code],SIH.[Country of Origin of Goods],SIH.[Bill-to Address 2] ,SIH.[Bill-to City] , SIH.[Bill-to Post Code], CR.Name ,C.Contact,SIH.[Total Boxes], CASE when SIL.[Dimension Group Code] = 'IOL' then I.[Group Description] 
END ,
CASE
    when  I.[EPCG License] = 1 then 'EPCG'
end,
case
    when SIL.[Dimension Group Code] = 'IOL' then 'DEEC'
    when I.[DEEC Lic_] = 1 then 'DEEC'
end as abcd
from [Sales Invoice Header] SIH ,[Customer] C, [Country_Region] CR,
 [Sales Invoice Line]  SIL,[Item] I where I.No_ =  SIL.No_ and SIL.[Document No_]='PEXP1213-110' and SIH.No_ = SIL.[Document No_] and C.No_ =  SIH.[Bill-to Customer No_] and C.[Country_Region Code] = CR.Code group by I.[Old Product Code], I.[Trade Name], I.[Short Name], SIH.[Sell-to Customer Name],SIH.[Sell-to City],SIH.[Customer Marks - 1],SIL.[Dimension Group Code],I.[Group Description], SIH.[Country of Origin of Goods], SIH.[Ship-to Name],SIH.[Ship-to Address], SIH.[Ship-to Address 2] , SIH.[Ship-to City], SIH.[Ship-to Post Code],SIH.[Bill-to Name],SIH.[Bill-to Address],SIH.[Bill-to Address 2],SIH.[Bill-to City] , SIH.[Bill-to Post Code],SIH.[Total Boxes],C.Contact ,CR.Name,I.[Base Box UOM], I.[EPCG License],I.[DEEC Lic_]
```

Comment: can you post the code of where you are showing the values

Comment: <% Response.Write(rs("Old Product Code")) %>
<% Response.Write(rs("Trade Name")) %>
 [<% Response.Write(rs("GD")) %>] [<% Response.Write(rs("DEEC"))%>][<% Response.Write(rs("EPCG"))%>] &quot;Mfg Dt and Exp Dt as per Annexure enclosed&quot;<br />
<% Response.Write(rs("Qty")) %>
  &nbsp;
 <% Response.Write(rs("Base Box UOM")) %> this is my asp code...posted sql code in the question

Answer (score 0):

You need to solve it programmatically like

```
if cstr(rs("Old Product Code"))="[]" then
   response.write("")
else 
   response.write(rs("Old Product Code"))
end if
```